# Fedora: SSH connection refused

Tags: ssh, fedora

I'm trying to connect my Ubuntu host to a fedora laptop via ssh in order to share files over Ethernet. I have OpenSSH server started on fedora (via `service sshd start`) and I already executed the command `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` in order to allow incoming ssh connections. Moreover the IPv4 address on the server is set by `ifconfig enp2s0f0 192.168.10.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`. But whenever I type `ssh -A -Y 192.168.10.10` or `ssh -4 192.168.10.10`; I get always an error message showing "ssh: connect to host 192.168.10.10 port 22: Connection refused", even after having the firewall disabled using `service iptables stop`.

`iptables -n -L -v` output on fedora shows:

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 11652 packets, 2859K bytes)  pkts bytes
> target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes
> target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11759 packets, 1665K bytes)  pkts bytes
> target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

`iptables -n -L -v` output on ubuntu shows:

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 210K packets, 16M bytes) pkts bytes target prot opt source destination
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) pkts bytes target prot opt source destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 209K packets, 15M bytes) pkts bytes target prot opt source destination

Executing `route -n` within the server, gives the following output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0f0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

executing `sudo route -n` within the Ubuntu client machine, gives the following output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp14s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp14s0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp14s0
```

`ip r` on client machine:

```
default via 192.168.10.1 dev enp14s0  proto static  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp14s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp14s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.10  metric 100
```

`arping -I enp14s0 192.168.10.10` on client machine, got stuck at:

```
ARPING 192.168.10.10 from 192.168.10.10 enp14s0
```

output of `sudo tcpdump -n -i any port 22`:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
01:09:28.363302 IP 192.168.10.10.58906 > 192.168.10.10.22: Flags [S], seq 506055200, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 33913 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
01:09:28.363357 IP 192.168.10.10.58906 > 192.168.10.10.22: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 506055201, win 0, length 0
01:09:28.354895 IP 192.168.10.10.58906 > 192.168.10.10.22: Flags [S], seq 2349767060, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 34911 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
01:09:28.354948 IP 192.168.10.10.22 > 192.168.10.10.58908: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2349767061, win 0, length 0
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46005/discussion-on-question-by-user6039980-fedora-ssh-connection-refused).

Comment: Is firewalld running? Note that this is the default configuration.

Comment: Can you please post your routing table?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the routing table can be found in the last question update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want to connect to the `enp2s0f0` interface of the server (all other interfaces (except loopback) are `DOWN`).

From the logs you can see that DHCP requests on that interface are timing out. From the output of `ip a` you can see that the interface only has an IPv6 link-local address.

You should either fix DHCP or manually assign an IPv4 address to the interface (`ip addr add x.x.x.x/24 dev enp2s0f0`). Alternatively you can use IPv6.

EDIT: More questions:

- Are the 2 machines directly connected?
- Can you tell us more about the client? What do `ip a`, `ip r`, and `iptables-save` output on the client?
- What does `iptables-save` output on the server?  Note that `iptables -vnL` doesn't print all the rules.
- Can you ping the server from the client? (e.g. `ping 192.168.10.10`)
- Can you arp ping the server from the client? (e.g. `arping -I eth0 192.168.10.10`) do you get a reply? is the MAC address in the reply correct? (it should be `20:89:84:77:4b:2a`).
- If you run tcpdump on the server (`tcpdump -n -i any port 22`) and try ssh-ing in what does tcpdump output?

EDIT 2: Your client and server should have different IP addresses. Make the client 192.168.10.9 and the server 192.168.10.10.

Comment: I was wrongly thinking that the ipv4 settings on the client interface points to the server ip, while it is supposed to be the client ip. changing the ip solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your rule is never reached because of the REJECT rule (just before), which is applied to all the packets that don't match preceding rules.

What happen if you use :

`iptables`**`-I INPUT 1`**`-p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

(i.e. insert the rule at the beginning of the table)

Edit : some more suggestions

- Check that sshd is actually listening :

  ```
  ss --tcp --listening -n -p
  ```
- Add the `-v` option when showing the iptables (this adds a packet count for each rule, so that you can see which one are used)
- try both IPv4 and IPv6 (with `-4` and `-6` options for the `ssh` command)

Comment: the error still occurs after executing that command.

Comment: I cannot see any REJECT in the OP: am I blind or mad?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the question was edited, there is now more info and the firewall is completely disabled (so this is not a firewall problem as I thought at first)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to connect to the wrong IP.

In the ss command you see something like 'Local Address' 192.168.122.1, but you try to connect to the IP 192.168.10.10.

Would you please give us the network configuration of the server?
It would be enough if you paste the whole output of executing `ip a` in the server.

Comment: please check my question's last update.